# Is the mixture of two regular distributions regular itself?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have two [regular distributions](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS6840/2012sp/cs6840_3_14_notes.pdf) $D_1, D_2$. My questions is: is a mixture of them regular, too? 
(by mixture I mean a distribution that, for an arbitrary $0<\alpha<1$, samples with probability $\alpha$ from $D_1$ and with probability $1-\alpha$ from $D_2$)

We can also replace the regularity condition with the monotone hazard rate condition and ask the same question.